# Alternative for getting payment method while using script tag webhook

Tags: shopify

I want to get the type of payment method chosen by the user. I am using 
[ScriptTag](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/scripttag) to show a confirmation dialog on [Order Status Page](https://help.shopify.com/manual/orders/status-tracking).

The problem is confirmation dialog is shown to the user for every type of payment, where I want to show it to the user only if the mode of payment is `Cash On Delivery`.

One way to do it is

1. Set up an `order/create` [webhook](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/webhook) and get the details of payment method chosen, check if the user has selected `Cash On Delivery` option. and then only show a confirmation dialog to the user on `Order Status Page`

The problem with this approach is it makes showing confirmation dialog slower.

Is there any other way to do it?

Note: Not asking for code, just a direction to think in :)